ConditionPathExists alternative in old systemd service file
ExecConditionPathExists requires systemd version 244. So I thought an alternative could be
/usr/bin/test -d /some/path

But unfortunately ExecCondition also needs a newer version of systemd (243). I need to get this working with systemd versions 219 and lower. How could I probably accomplish that?


ExecConditionPathExists requires systemd version 244.

No, ExecConditionPathExists does not exist in any released version of systemd. The only similar addition in v244 was ExecConditionEx=.
If you meant [Unit] ConditionPathExists=, that only requires systemd v12.

Sorry for blending the names of both conditions. ConditionPathExists was added in version 244 ExecCondition in 243 according to https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.unit.html.

The documentation is wrong. 'ConditionPathExists=' was added in v12. (In fact, most of the "Added in version" tags for pre-v200ish options are completely wrong – e.g. 'Wants=' and 'Requires=' were already present in v1; they are most certainly not a v201 addition.)

Thanks! You are completely right. But I ran into another problem... I wanted to use 'ConditionPathExists=/opt/someapp/$(uname -r)' but unfortunately I cannot use bash variables here... any ideas on how to solve this problem?
